# View full website, not mobile version on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, redirect, mobile-website

I have a script that detects whether you're an iPhone user or not and redirects to a more iPhone friendly page.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) 
    {
        location.replace("http://domain.com/iphone/");
    }
</script>
```

This works great but has one problem. It is convention to offer the user the ability to view the *full* web page.  However, if I link to the root, obviously the redirect is going to send them to the mobile version!

Any ideas on how to include if click on the link from `/iphone/`, they can go to `/` and stay there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Query String is the way to go ( as the others have said above). Looking at Facebook, if you click on the 'full site' link on the mobile site, it redirects to www.facebook.com/login.php?m2w  - the m2w is probably MobileToWeb and this will prevent the site redirecting the user to the mobile site.

Comment: Yes, Noted. However, the problem is all the other anchors will be linked to href="/". So, a query string to maintain state wont work unless a cookie is used. It may work on the first request, but not when a user browsers to another page, then click back home. They will be prompted shifted to the mobile site again.

Answer (score 8):

When the user arrives, determine their browser type - mobile or full - and set a cookie with this value.  Use this cookie value to decide what version of the site to display.  AS you mention, offer a link to the "full" site to the mobile users, but if they click it, run a quick script to update the cookie to the "full" value and then redirect them to the full site.  Their cookie is now set for the full site, so they won't get bounced back to the mobile site.

Now, if cookie are a problem, you could use something like PHP to set a session values to maintain the full/mobile status of the session, but that's probably getting beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: You can do this without the intermediate script, by having a query string like "?i-want-to-use-the-main-site=1" (obviously less complex than that XD), setting a cookie if that query string is there, and redirecting if neither the cookie or the query string are present.

Comment: and if they have cookies turned off you can just set it in the query string: `?preventMobileRedirect=true` or something

Comment: @Kolink: This is true. I was thinking in PHP, not JavaScript, but it works either way. I'll amend the answer though, that's more in the spirit of the original question.

Comment: @Joel: If users have cookies turned off, then you could fall back on a session value if you have some server side scripting to resort to.