# How to select web page by browser type

Tags: java, html, web

Is there a way to provide a user with a basic HTML webpage from the same link according to browser type? Specifically, when navigating to www.mysite.com via a desktop browser, the user sees one large web page, but navigating there from a mobile shows a smaller web page.

Comment: Probably this is what you are looking for:
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922653/classic-view-mobile-view-switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use style sheet to achieve this.

Screen will only display on the desktop, while handheld will only display on the mobile device.

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/03/how-to-build-a-mobile-website/#mobile-stylesheets

Answer (score 1):

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) [Responsive Design](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)  will help in what you'r trying to achieve.

So if you included the bootstrap library as part of your site, adding a class to your HTML tags will make it behave that way.

```
<body>
   <div class="visible-desktop">
      Content for big screen here
   </div>

   <div class="visible-phone">
      Content for phones here
   <div>
</body
```