# Go from mobile site to full site?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a website with HTML and Javascript. When someone goes on the full site with an iPhone or iPod Touch it redirects them. The problem is that I have a link on my mobile one to go back to the full site which doesn't work because it just redirects them back to the mobile site. Any help would be appreciated.

The javascript to redirect:

```
    <script language=javascript>
        <!--
        if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||       (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
            location.replace("Mobile version");
            }
            -->
    </script>
```

Comment: Possbile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181466/view-full-website-not-mobile-version-on-iphone?rq=1

Comment: I see that one but it didn't help me

Answer (score 1):

Add a cookie when the user selects to go to the full site. Then in your redirect to mobile check to make sure that cookie doesn't exist.

To set the cookie:

```
var expire = new Date();
expire.setTime(expire.getTime()+(1*24*60*60*1000));
document.cookie = "nomobile=true; expires="+expire+"; path=/";
```

To read the cookie:

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
if (!getCookie("nomobile")) {
    //USE THIS AREA TO CHECK THE USER AGENT AND REDIRECT AS YOU CURRENTLY ARE
}
```

Comment: Any help how to do that? Noobie here.

Comment: You can use the jQuery cookies plugin, which is probably the easisest way to do cookies. Note that to use it, you'd also have  to have jquery imported

Comment: Added code examples, I usually use PHP to get/set cookies instead of JavaScript. That said I'm not 100% sure the reading cookie stuff works properly, but I have no reason to believe it will fail, as it didn't in a quick test.

Answer (score 0):

One simple fix would be to check if the referrer is your own website. It your coming from your own site, then don't redirect to the mobile version.